# Selectively preventing the debugger from stopping on 1st chance exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, task-parallel-library, visual-studio-debugging

I know I can prevent the Visual Studio debugger from stopping on certain kind of exceptions when they're thrown (via the Ctrl-Alt-E "Exceptions" dialog). But what if want to control this from code, for some specific places rather than on the all-or-none basis? For example:

```
try
{
    SomeMethod(token);
}
catch (OperationCancelledException)
{
    return false;
}

// ...

void SomeMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
    // ...

    // I don't want the debugger to stop on the following line
    #pragma ignore(OperationCancelledException, true)
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    #pragma ignore(OperationCancelledException, false)
}
```

I use the hypothetic `#pragma ignore` to illustrate what I mean, but does something like this actually exist?

**UPDATE** to address "Unclear what you're asking" closure vote. Try this code in the debugger: https://dotnetfiddle.net/npMk6r. Make sure all exceptions are enabled in the Ctrl-Alt-E dialog. The debugger will be stopping on the `throw new OperationCanceledException("cancelled1")` line upon each iteration of the loop. I don't want that to happen as it's annoying. Yet, I do want it to stop on the last throw outside the loop, `throw new OperationCanceledException("cancelled2")` (or anywhere else, for that matter).

Comment: what if you just have an empty `catch{}` block have you tried that..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE, The debugger will stop on `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` anyway, unless I disable `OperationCancelledException` (or `TaskCancelledException`) in the Ctrl-Alt-E dialog. I don't want to swallow the exception, I just want the debugger to ignore it for certain places in my code, not everywhere.

Comment: Would `DebuggerHiddenAttribute` be a viable option?

Comment: In Visual Studio breakpoints can be made to execute stuff. They are called tracepoints then. Maybe tracepoints could be used to change the settings for exceptions. Don't know how, though, and there are no macros in VS2012 and above, so it's a very long shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I'd use [`DebuggerNonUserCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute for this.

To illustrate that, here's a modified version of your [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/npMk6r). The debugger won't stop on `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` even though `OperationCanceledException` is enabled in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> Exceptions dialog.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestApp
{
    static class Ext
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
        public static bool TryThrowIfCancellationRequested(
            this CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                // debugger won't stop here, because of DebuggerNonUserCode attr
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                return true;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static bool SomeMethod(CancellationToken token)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return token.TryThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (!SomeMethod(cts.Token))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you could have used `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` instead of `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in this particular case, but the above approach illustrates the concept which can be extended to any other exception.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you @Noserati. Do you think it's possible to create a generic version of `TryThrowIfCancellationRequested`-like method, something I could pass an `Action` and a type of exception to ignore to?

Comment: @avo, I don't think so, because `DebuggerNonUserCode` cannot be applied to a lambda. If you throw inside the lambda, the debugger will stop. Unless you define an actual method for each lambda, in which case it might work. Needless to say, I suppose by "ignoring" you mean "handling/logging" an exception somehow, right?

Answer (score 1):

you try the following way:

> When "Just My Code" is enabled, Visual Studio in some cases will break on the line that throws the exception and display an error message that says "exception not handled by user code." This error is benign. You can press F5 to continue from it, and see the exception-handling behavior that is demonstrated in the examples below. **To prevent Visual Studio from breaking on the first error, just uncheck the "Just My Code" checkbox under Tools, Options, Debugging, General**.

from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

What you want can be expressed as

```
try 
{   // #pragma ignore(OperationCancelledException, true)
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
catch (OperationCancelledException op)
{    //    #pragma ignore(OperationCancelledException, false)
     // ignore
}
```

But this is considered a bad practise. Exceptions should be somehow handled. At least for some debugging reasons.

Comment: The debugger will stop on `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` anyway, unless I disable `OperationCancelledException` (or `TaskCancelledException`) in the Ctrl-Alt-E dialog. I don't want to swallow the exception, I just want the debugger to ignore it for certain places in my code, not everywhere.

Comment: so..but if you have no code to execute there nothing will happen so having it there with no code will do nothing..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: He doesn't want the debugger to break.

Comment: can he use some # defined if conditional then and check if debbuger or something to that effect

Comment: @DJ, *can he use some # defined if conditional then* - please post an answer if you could put an example of that.

Comment: I am not sure why you can't just use an empty `catch {}` maybe I am  not understanding your issue

Comment: I updated my question and I hope I made it more clear what I'm asking.

Comment: I think I understand what you want. Some fine granular way to just hide some exceptions for some arbitrary code blocks. As far as I know this can only be achieved through handling the exception and setting the exceptions to just unhandled exceptions in the debugger exceptions dialog.